# Trouble designing an ALU

Tags: digital-logic

I have trouble designing an ALU. Here are my logic boxes:

[image]

But how can we implement a digital circuit which will choose the operation:If I use multiplexers all the operations will be done at the same time.Is it the way to go? Or is there another way? Also how can we select which operation will be performed?

Comment: Does it matter that all of those operations will be performed at the same time, when you only pick and use the result of one of them? (Only multiplex the outputs)

Comment: Okay but if 2 operations have different number of input numbers(NOT with XNOR) for example how can we do that?

Comment: Um, just wire all the A0's together, all A1's, all B0's and all B1's to form your A0, A1, B0 and B1 inputs to the entire ALU. If a particular logic block does not have the B inputs, then then value of that input will be ignored for that particular operation. (I only meant to hint in the comments, I promise)

Comment: Have a look at the equivalent logic of a 74181.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. The answer depends on how you have designed to interface the ALU with the rest of your design. Is this for simulation only or are you actually developing an ALU for hardware?

Comment: You could fed the output bits of each operation through separate 2 input AND gates with an enable line. Only when you select a specific operation by setting the enable line to a 1 will that operation propagate to the output. And when the enable line is 0, the operation will output zero. Not better than the mux, just another way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with the way you suggested. It may cost a few more gates than a highly optimised solution, but gates are (usually) cheap and designer's time is not.

It is far more important to design something correct, clear and understandable, and your approach can achieve that.

Plus, any synthesis tool will aggressively optimise whatever you produce anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to put a MUX on each output bit of the ALU. For example, consider an 8-bit ALU with 4 different ALU instructions. You’ll have bit 0 of each of the four logical units of the ALU go to the first MUX; bit 1 will go to the second MUX etc.

[image: ALU]

[source](https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Echitta/coldvl/alu.html)

The control unit can then select the ALU operation by varying the MUX select lines.

P.S.

This is how you memory map a series of outputs onto a data bus. It’s a very useful technique to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is omit individual gates prior to the MUX and feed a Karnaugh map instead. Let A vs B control the 4Way where S0 vs S1 once did. All 16 logics are now possible.

Omitting the adder is also possible, but a little tougher to explain. These MUX usually come with a twin in the same IC (74CBT3253 for example). Let that do something useful by comparing A vs B.

EQn+1=AnVsBn(EQn,LT,GT,EQn). Choose the comparison type < = > with LT EQo GT. Set these controls low to disable comparison for pure logic. A<B reveals all of A-B's borrows. A>B reveals all of B-A's borrows. Positive logic borrow with positive logic operands is normal with XOR Karnaugh mapped for subtraction.

Real XOR the Karnaugh half-result with the prior comparison half-result to make a full result. Maybe another XOR inverts B to make addition. 74LVC2G86 gives both XOR this slice wants and fits with CBT3253 on an SSOP to DIP28 converter. Wire the empty backside where SOIC pads are bigger.

Ohyeah, ripple. CBT3253 are transmission gate MUX, so series current solves a chain of switches in one go. Either Propagate borrow through when EQual (250pS RC delay) or replace by LT or GT (serving Generate or Annihilate when subtracting). MUX is tricked to decode series prefixes internally as it steers the switches.

Two ICs per slice. No special board. No ripple. No unused results wastefully calculated. Already MUX'd down to a single answer.

Comment: A visual presentation may help where words fail to convey intended meaning: *what is* `A vs B`, a `4Way` or one of `All 16 logics`?